# Activate venv from makefile and transfer activation to bash session

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a virtual env. Name it test-venv.

```
python3 -m venv test-venv
source test-venv/bin/activate
```

After that my bash session is working with the venv activated.

I would like to put that in a make command.

*Makefile*

```
evenv: # Enter test-venv
   source test-venv/bin/activate
```

My problem is that, I guess another bash session is created when I execute a make target, so when the target execution finish, I am not longer in the venv.

How can I achieve this, if it is possible?

Comment: It is not possible.  This same question was asked less than a day ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274023/how-to-activate-a-virtual-environment-for-use-outside-the-makefile

Comment: @MadScientist this question or similar is asked multiple times per week

Comment: Yes.  Seems like a basic conceptual stumbling block regarding processes, subprocesses, and how they work together.

Comment: I could not find that. Thank you. Would you recommend to delete this one?